# Point instance in 3.5

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I'm following tutorials on the blender guru page so I can learn the program well.  Unfortunately, the tutorials are using an older blender program.

For instance, I'm following the tutorial on the gumdrop and it says that I need a points instance node in 3.5.  The only problem is, there isn't one.

Was it replaced with something else that I can use?  This is all the points options that Blender 3.5 has.

[image]

Comment: There isn't one called that in Blender 3 and above. Maybe Instance on Points under the Instances category?

Comment: That Blender Guru tutorial was done in Blender 2.92 in the early days of Geometry Nodes. There have been lots of changes since then so I'd look for a more up to date tutorial maybe using 3.5.